# Need to select output using substr and instr function in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My table contains below data

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM      VALUE DB_NAME                   PROPERTY_NAME                  PROPERTY_VALUE
------------------- ---------- -------------------------
2021-07-24 07:41:42      15670 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 07:46:42      15971 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:26:42      21953 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:31:42      22255 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:36:42      22556 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-20 08:13:05        554 opp201p.allstate.com      DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 01:57:18       5441 opp201p.allstate.com      DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 09:15:48        671 opp213s.allstate.com      DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 09:30:47        432 opp213s.allstate.com      DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
```

My desired output is eliminating .allstate.com

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM      VALUE DB_NAME                   PROPERTY_NAME                  PROPERTY_VALUE
------------------- ---------- ------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
2021-07-24 07:41:42      15670 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 07:46:42      15971 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:26:42      21953 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:31:42      22255 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:36:42      22556 ewp5s                     DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-20 08:13:05        554 opp201p                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 01:57:18       5441 opp201p                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 09:15:48        671 opp213s                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 09:30:47        432 opp213s                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
```

If i use below query its returning blanks in DB_NAME column. Can anyone advice?

```
select 
    collection_timestamp
   ,VALUE
   ,substr(target_name,1,instr(target_name,'.',1,1)- 1) db_name
   ,PROPERTY_NAME
   ,PROPERTY_VALUE  
FROM sysman.mgmt_metrics_raw;
```

---

```
COLLECTION_TIMESTAM      VALUE DB_NAME                   PROPERTY_NAME                  PROPERTY_VALUE
------------------- ---------- ------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
2021-07-24 07:41:42      15670                           DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 07:46:42      15971                           DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:26:42      21953                           DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:31:42      22255                           DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-24 09:36:42      22556                           DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-20 08:13:05        554 opp201p                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 01:57:18       5441 opp201p                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 09:15:48        671 opp213s                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
2021-07-22 09:30:47        432 opp213s                   DataGuardStatus                Physical Standby
```

Comment: Do you need to remove `.allstate.com`, as you say in words, or do you need to remove the period and everything that comes after it, no matter what that is (as your query does, when there are periods in the string)? Or is `allstate.com` the ***only*** possible string following a period, if there is a period in the string at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use `case`. The following query produces the desired result.

```
select 
    collection_timestamp
   ,VALUE
   ,case when instr(target_name,'.') == 0 then target_name
    else substr(target_name,1,instr(target_name,'.') - 1) end as db_name
   ,PROPERTY_NAME
   ,PROPERTY_VALUE  
FROM sysman.mgmt_metrics_raw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate a period to the first argument of `instr`, like so:

```
with
  tbl (target_name) as (
    select 'ewp5s'                from dual union all
    select 'opp201p.allstate.com' from dual
  )
select substr(target_name, 1, instr(target_name || '.', '.') - 1) as db_name
from   tbl
;

DB_NAME 
--------
ewp5s
opp201p
```

This should be much faster than any solution using regular expressions.

In the call to `instr`, note that the third and fourth arguments are 1 by default, so you don't need to give them explicitly (although there's nothing wrong with giving them).